# wpdb custom tables without plugin

Tags: customization, mysql, wpdb

I am using custom tables, with $wpdb, trying to perform basic queries at the moment. I can't find anything on manually creating tables then using them with $wpdb, everything is plugin related. I really do not want to use a plugin. My tables are named Wp_customtable and wp_customtable_meta. custom table has a foreign key to wp_user, and wp_customtable is connected to wp_customtable_meta. I run queries in the SQL, my tables work flawlessly with WP default tables. I run the $wpdb queries with custom tables in my app, I get undefined errors in wp-db.php. assuming I have to make my tables known in that file? Is there a way to do this without adding a plugin? What should I include/change inside wp-db.php, so WordPress $wpdb class can find my custom tables?

Comment: So you have bugs in your code.... In this kind of questions if you don't show code it is as if you you never asked the question ;)

Comment: Is it really that hard to format a question properly? Please take your time to read [ask] and keep that info in mind for further questions. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of errors? Debug information?

Comment: My table is named wp_customtable in the DB.

$wpdb->wp_customtable was undefined, even thou $wpdb->wp_users is valid.

 I needed to use $wpdb->prefix.customtable to access wpdb with my custom table. 

i can also edit the wp-db file to include it manually so i dont have to use prefix, but its waste of time imo.